# Code works in one Visual Studio C++ project, but not the other

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

Here is the code in question.

```
uint16_t get_unaligned_16(uint16_t *ptr)
{
#pragma pack(push, 1)
    struct packed {
      uint16_t __v;
    } *__p = (packed *)(ptr);
#pragma pack(pop)
    return __p->__v;
}
```

Both projects are targeting the same VC++ runtime (2013).

Here is the exact error from the compiler.

```
error C2065: 'packed' : undeclared identifier error C2059: syntax error : ')' 
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'get_unaligned_32' 
error C2059: syntax error : ';' error C2059: syntax error : 'type' 
error C2065: 'packed' : undeclared identifier error C2059: syntax error : ')' 
warning C4013: 'get_unaligned_32' undefined; assuming extern returning int
```

Any ideas why this doesn't compile in one project, but does in another?

[image: picture of code that doesn't compile]

Answer (score 2):

In C, you must use the word `struct` with struct names: `struct packed` is the name of the struct being defined.  In C++, you can omit that keyword, which you do here, referring to it only as `(packed *)` in your cast of `ptr`.  I would guess that the file that gave the errors is a .c file, or is compiled as C.